# Detecting which municipality lies on which region?

Tags: r

I am again struggling with spatial data. I have to shapefiles. One is the municipality shapefile and the other the region shapefile.

I have a shapefile that contains 106 regions of Switzerland. crs system is LV03.

| Region | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | listMultipolygon |
| 2 | listMultipolygon |

And a shapefille of every municipality in switzerland. CRS is LV95

| Municipality | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | listMultipolygon |
| 2 | listMultipolygon |

Now, I used the following code. I transform the shapefile g_shp municipality shapefile into LV03 CRS. And then use st_intersects to find out which municipalities are in which region. And I check it with the first region.

```
ms_shp <- st_read("CH.shp")
g_shp <- st_read("HOHEITSGEBIET.shp")
g_shp$geometry <- st_transform(g_shp$geometry, 21781)
d <- st_intersects(ms_shp,g_shp)
```

But when I gave that

```
d[[1]]
```

```
[1]   78  660  665  712  777  810 1177 1187 1214 1351 1378 1383 1497 1706 2014 2080
```

It came this output, but region 1 contains only one municipality. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You've only shared the `.shp`  part of the Shapefile. Make a .zip with .shp, .shx, .dbf and .prj and share that for us.

Comment: i changed it now. It should contain all part of the shapefile

Comment: Polygon/polygon overlay is tricky, at best, even if the smaller polygons were used to generate the larger. If the principal issue is just poor registration, you can use the *centroids* of the smaller features for point-in-poly operation. If there's significant overlap, then a true intersection might be necessary, with proportions by area of overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot the first `ms_shp` object (green) and put the `g_shp` object under it you'll see they don't line up perfectly:

[image]

The polygon indexes listed in your `st_intersects` result all have overlaps with polygon 1 - in some cases very tiny overlaps, but there are some that look significant. Perhaps there's been boundary changes between the two data sets, or one has been digitised at a different precision to the other.